# configure: error: cannot find the required ev_run() function despite trying to link with -lev

Tags: i3-wm

I'm trying to install i3-gaps on Ubuntu and I've come across this problem:

I run

`../configure --prefix=/usr --sysconfdir=/etc --disable-sanitizers`
 
and then I get this error message:

`configure: error: cannot find the required ev_run() function despite trying to link with -lev`

Comment: Please provide more details - your Ubuntu version, i3-wm version, i3-gaps version. Add this info to the question.

Answer (score 0):

You should install all [needed build dependencies (`-dev` packages)](https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/bionic/i3-wm) with :

```
sudo apt-get build-dep i3-wm
```

and then retry your `./configure` procedure.

---

You may be also interested with adding PPA to your system:

- `i3blocks-gaps` for Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (*xenial*) from [`ppa:monettes/i3wm-gaps`](https://launchpad.net/~monettes/+archive/ubuntu/i3wm-gaps)
- `i3-gaps-wm` for Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (*xenial*) and Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (*bionic*) from [`ppa:kgilmer/regolith`](https://launchpad.net/~kgilmer/+archive/ubuntu/regolith)